# MPI - Error sending random int to root process

Tags: c, mpi

Here is my piece of code:

```
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_size);

int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_rank);

int *rbuf , arr[world_size];
if (world_rank == 0)
{
    rbuf = (int *) malloc(world_size * 1 * sizeof(int));
}
else
{
    rbuf[0] = rand() % 100;
    MPI_Send(rbuf , 1 , MPI_INT , 0 , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
if (world_rank == 0)
{
    MPI_Gather(arr , world_size , MPI_INT , rbuf , 1 , MPI_INT , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for (int i = 0; i < world_size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d " , arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I want to generate a random number at every process which is not the root process. Then I want each such process to send the number generated to the root process, ie. the root process should gather all the numbers generated at each process.

When I am trying to run this code, I get the error:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Gather: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Gather(896)......: MPI_Gather(sbuf=0x7ffc3b23c180, scount=10, MPI_INT, rbuf=0x564a753dc790, rcount=1, MPI_INT, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Gather_impl(718).: 
MPIR_Gather(678)......: 
MPIR_Gather_intra(184): 
MPIR_Localcopy(74)....: Message truncated; 40 bytes received but buffer size is 4
```

(PS. I run this program using `mpirun -n 10 ./helloworld`)

Comment: After you receive input from another function (or the user), and before using it as an array size... test its value against sane limits, and if in doubt, print out the value. I'm not saying that's the problem here, but it's a good habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_Gather` send messages from all ranks to root and receive itself it does not need `MPI_Send`.

I changed your example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_size);
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_rank);

  srand(time(NULL)+world_rank);
  int *rbuf,*sender;
  if (world_rank == 0)
  {
    rbuf = (int *) malloc(world_size * 1 * sizeof(int));
  }
  sender = (int *) malloc( 1 * sizeof(int));
  sender[0] = rand() % 100;

  MPI_Gather(sender , 1 , MPI_INT , rbuf , 1 , MPI_INT , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if (world_rank == 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < world_size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d " , rbuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't MPI_Gather() be in world_rank == 0 as the root process gathers all the numbers generated by other processes?

Comment: @Sparker0i No, all ranks run `MPI_Gather()` and send their messages to root. Even root send the message to root (from send buffer to receive buffer).

Comment: as a side note, you can simplify a bit by having `sender` on the stack (e.g. `malloc` of one `int` is a bit of an overkill here).